# Updating location state in the route is not reflecting on the parent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a react app and I am using react-router for routing. 
I have created a `<PrivateRoute>` component which renders the component only when the user is logged in. In the app, the title in the header keeps on changing which will be passed through the `<PrivateRoute>` definition. Below is my code:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, title, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !empty(getSession()) ? getComponent(props, title, Component): (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;

function getComponent(props, title, Component){

  if(notUndefinedAndNull(title)){
    props.location.state = {
      ...props.location.state,
      pageTitle: title
    }
  }

  return <Component {...props} />
}
```

The title is passed when defining the `<PrivateRoute>` component and is then updated in the location state. However, when the page is refreshed, the title is not reflected in the location state.

The header sits at the top of all pages like below

```
.
├── App # Top-level component holding Header, Pages and Bottom Nav component
|   ├── Header
|   ├── Pages
|   |   ├── New component(page) will be mounted/unmounted here depending on the Route
|   ├── Bottom Nav
```

The routes are defined under the `<Pages>` component and the title set in the location state needs to be propagated to the parent component `<Header>`.

Comment: Did you mean your route is getting changed but not the page content?

Comment: @Sohan  My route is getting changed, and the page content as well, but the state of location which I am updating in the <PrivateRoute>, is not propagating to the parent component

Comment: Can you update the code in the code sandbox for more clarity?